# LAPack dpbsv returns 3 for positive definite matrix

Tags: swift, lapack

I am trying to use the LAPACK banded symmetric matrix solver dpbsv. I am testing the matrix:

```
4,  2,  0,   0, 0
2   4,  3,   0, 0
0,  3, 11,  7,  0
0,  0,  7, 11,  5
0,  0,  0,  5, 13
```

Mathematica tells me that this matrix is positive definite, with a determinate of 3684

I am using swift and have constructed the array

```
var a: [Double] = [ 0, 2,  3,  7,  5,
                    4, 4, 11, 11, 13]
var b: [Double] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And I am calling dpbsv as

```
    var uplo = Int8("U".utf8.first!) // set to 'U'

    var n = __CLPK_integer(5)
    var kd = __CLPK_integer(1)
    var ldab = kd + 1
    var nrhs = __CLPK_integer(1)
    var ldb = __CLPK_integer(5)
    var info: __CLPK_integer = 0

    dpbsv_(&uplo,
           &n,
           &kd,
           &nrhs,
           &a,
           &ldab,
           &b,
           &ldb,
           &info)

    if info != 0 {
        // here info is 3, indicating non-positive definite.
        NSLog("error \(info)")
    }
```

Any idea what the issue is here? Am I interpreting the parameters to dpbsv_ correctly? I've tried other matrices that Mathematica claims are pos-def with the same result.

Comment: I updated the matrix to make the diagonal 4, 5, 7, 11, 13 and the off-diagonal terms all 0 as `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 7, 11, 13]`, and it still says that it can't solve it (info = 1)

Comment: And if I change to simply ` a = [4, 5, 7, 11, 13]` and `kd = 0` it solves it, so there is something I am not understanding about the input..

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently, what LAPACK documents as rows need to be coded as columns in swift. So, if the array is changed to

```
[ 0,  4,
  2,  4,
  3, 11,
  7, 11,
  5, 13]
```

everything works fine.